# How to rotate this cube over Z axis using css?

Tags: css, css-transforms

[image]

I want to rotate this cube 90deg to the left, so the final destination of the red T will be on the right face of the cube, the green line will be on the bottom.

On the initial position of the cube, the T was on the left face of the cube and the green line was the X axis, red line was the Y and the cyan line was Z axis.

The transitions for this cube is now like this after the initial position;

```
rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)
```

I assume in this position I should rotate the cube over red line to the left to get what I wanted. But if I rotate it 90 deg over on Y axis assuming the red line is still the Y axis, this is what I get;

```
rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg)
```

[image]

I also tried rotation over X and Z but thoose does not give me the result I want.

**Here is the fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/uv1Lt16z/1/

```js
reset = function() {
  document.getElementById('cube').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)";
}

rotateLeftX = function() {
  document.getElementById('cube').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)";
};

rotateLeftY = function() {
  document.getElementById('cube').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg)";
};

rotateLeftZ = function() {
  document.getElementById('cube').style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(180deg)";
};

reset();
```

```css
#experiment {
  margin-top: 20%;
  -webkit-perspective: 140px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 35px;
}
#cube {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
}
#cube .ctop {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(35px);
}
#cube .cfront {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(35px);
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  border-left: 3px solid red;
}
#cube .cright {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(35px);
}
#cube .cback {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(35px);
}
#cube .cleft {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(35px);
  border-bottom: 3px solid cyan;
}
#cube .cdown {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(35px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="rotateLeftX()">Rotate X axis</button>
<button onclick="rotateLeftY()">Rotate Y axis</button>
<button onclick="rotateLeftZ()">Rotate Z axis</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<div id="experiment">
  <div id="cube">
    <div class="face ctop">

    </div>
    <div class="face cfront">

    </div>
    <div class="face cright">

    </div>
    <div class="face cback">

    </div>
    <div class="face cleft"> <span style="color: red;font-size: 72px;font-weight: bold;position: absolute;">T</span>
    </div>
    <div class="face cdown">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle.

Comment: Ok, here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/uv1Lt16z/1/

Comment: in case somebody needs rotating element over Y axis: http://jsfiddle.net/uv1Lt16z/7/

Comment: And here is so it would look like it is in from front but spinnings: http://jsfiddle.net/uv1Lt16z/8/

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want : The transforms are not harmonic, but the desired result is obtained.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThePragmatick/t98gv5e9/

`transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg);`

Comment: What I want is this ;

    `rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(180deg)`

But the transformation should be smooth and harmonic. Like it is rotating to the left.

Comment: Yea that's what I wanted but what is the logic, I could not wrap my head around this rotation thing. In the initial position the red line is Y axis, the green line is X axis and cyan is the Z axis. At first I thought that the axises are rotating as the cube rotates. But I can see that is not always the case. I should be able to reach the result I wanted only rotating the cube on one direction, whether it is x, or y or z. But what you have is a change on both three axises, 90 deg on x, 90 deg on y and 90 deg on z direction.